# Why GetLastError() returns ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I've created a VS2010 C++ empty solution with this code below:

```
#include "conmat.h"
#include "resource.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <afxwin.h>
#include <atlimage.h>

void main(){    
    CImage bmp;
    bmp.LoadFromResource(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),RES_BMP);   

    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I added a BMP file as a resource. Why is it not working?

---

here is conmat.rc file, that must contain (in my mind) bitmap picture created in paint

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Русский (Россия) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_RUS)
LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Bitmap
//

RES_BMP                 BITMAP                  "in.bmp"
#endif    // Русский (Россия) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use MFC in a Win32 console application. Please follow the tricks described in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297862/Convert-Win-Console-Application-to-MFC) how to properly do so

Comment: If your app is a console app, it should initialize MFC (in your code, AfxGetInstanceHandle() is likely to return NULL actually). Use AfxWinInit to set up MFC (handles, etc):

AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0);

If this is just a quick example you made, then we may need a working one to go further..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` instead of `AfxGetInstanceHandle()`.

Comment: what's the differwnce between this functions?

Comment: GetModuleHandle() is a win32 function that (unsurprisingly) returns the handle of the 'current' 'module' when called with a NULL parameter ('current' = relative to where the function is called; 'module' = the physical object code unit (exe or dll). AfxGetInstanceHandle() is an MFC function that returns a global variable that is stored by MFC somewhere during initialisation (I can't remember from the top of my head where). The 'instance handle' is a framework concept, the 'module handle' is an OS concept.

Comment: @Roel: `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` does not return the **current** module. When called from a DLL, it will return the module handle of the module that started the process. Also, your interpretation of *instance* and *module* is about a mile off: Both are OS concepts, and mean the same thing today.

Comment: Oh yes I misremembered, the NULL version gets the original module. In the OP's case it happens to work because he doesn't have a dll. The 'instance' I'm talking about is what is returned by AfxGetInstanceHandle(), which used to coincide with the OS 'instance' back when that were different things. In the context of the question and my answer, they are very much two different things. I hope you don't expect me to explain all of the history and various concepts behind the various sorts of handles and how they map to MFC in an SO answer.

Comment: Again, a `HINSTANCE` and a `HMODULE` are the same thing. MFC doesn't use its own interpretation either; they are the same thing in MFC as they are in the Windows API. In the context of the question, they are the same thing. The real issue the OP was having is failing to initialize MFC's module state. If your interpretation were correct, both calls would return the same value.

Comment: I'm not talking about HINSTANCE and HMODULE. Please read carefully what the context of the question is before you say things that nobody was even talking about. The point is that MFC keeps an internal reference to an instance handle, which is returned by AfxGetInstanceHandle(). *That* instance (and yes, the value of that is the same as the the module and instance handles of the application) is a framework-provided abstraction. An abstraction that doesn't make much sense any more in 2014, but still an abstraction that is conceptually different from the underlying result of GetModuleHandle().

Comment: @Roel, so if i get you right, the  AfxGetInstanceHandle() function returns the HMODULE, which is the MFC concept. And HMODULE gets value during MFC initialization, so if i init MFC, this two function ( AfxGetInstanceHandle and GetModuleHandle) returns the same HANDLE, right?

Comment: Sorry, I only just saw your additional question. It's been a long time since 'instance handle' was really a thing (see e.g. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103644 ), and the whole discussion above is probably more confusing than helpful, which is why I swept the details under the rug in the first place. But yes, if you initialize MFC then GetModuleHandle(NULL) and AfxGetInstanceHandle() return what is essentially just a void*, and have the same value. But the whole thing of letting MFC abstract those things away (and even more so with their cousin, AfxGetResourceHandle) is confusing (tbc...)

Comment: and doesn't add anything. Just use GetModuleHandle(). Essentially, what is happening is this: win32 needs to know where in the memory space it can find a 'resource section', a memory space with menus, dialogs, bitmaps etc. Resource sections are a part of the PE file format, the Windows binary (as in .exe, .dll, ...) layout. Every dll and exe might have one. The 'instance handle' is a value set by Windows and is passed to WinMain or DllMain. That's how your exe or dll knows how it can be identified by Windows API's from all other loaded modules. The Petzold has more details if you want to know.